# Only one UITableView responds to touches

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, row

I have three classes (**SurePeople**, **MaybePeople**, **NopePeople**) in my **contentView**. They are all subclasses of the same `UITableView` **PeopleTableView**. Only difference is where they get their users array from. If users.count is equal to zero I change the constant of the heightAnchor of that tableView to zero to hide it.

When I click on the first Tableview-row of the first Tableview that is displayed, the method `didSelectRowAt` gets called, if I click on any other row, nothing happens.
What is going on?

---

contentView:

```
for controller in tableViewControllers {
    contentView.addSubview(controller)
    controller.delegateTVToSingleEvent = delegateSVToSingleEvent?.getSingleEventVC()
    controller.delegateTVToScrollView = self
    let heightCon = controller.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    heightCon.isActive = true
    heightCons.append(heightCon)
}
```

PeopleTableView:

```
class PeopleTableView: UIView, ReusableView {

    //MARK: - Properties & Variables
    var delegateTVToSingleEvent: tableViewToSingleEvent?
    var delegateTVToScrollView: tableViewToScrollView?
    var myEvent: Event
    var users: [User]! = [User]()

    //MARK: - GUI Objects
    let peopleTableView: UITableView = {
        let tableview = UITableView()
        return tableview
    }()

    let peopleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label       = UILabel()
        label.font      = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        label.text      = "Label:"
        label.textColor = .black
        return label
    }()

    //MARK: - Init & View Loading
    init(frame: CGRect, event: Event) {
        self.myEvent = event
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = LebensfitSettings.Colors.basicBackColor
        setupTableView()
        setupViews()
    }

    //MARK: - Setup
    func setupTableView() {
        peopleTableView.delegate            = self
        peopleTableView.dataSource          = self
        peopleTableView.register(TeilnehmerTVCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: TeilnehmerTVCell.reuseIdentifier)
        peopleTableView.tintColor           = .white
        peopleTableView.isScrollEnabled     = false
        peopleTableView.allowsSelection     = true
    }

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(peopleLabel)
        addSubview(peopleTableView)
    }

    func removeViews() {
        peopleTableView.removeFromSuperview()
        peopleLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func confBounds(){
        peopleLabel.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 15, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 25)
        peopleTableView.anchor(top: peopleLabel.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 5, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    }

    //MARK: - Methods
    func loadUsers() {
        setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        if users.count == 0 {
            removeViews()
            padding = 0
        } else {
            setupViews()
            padding = 15+25+5
        }
        self.updateConstraints()
        delegateTVToScrollView?.finishedLoadingParticipants()
    }

    //MARK: - Do not change Methods
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension PeopleTableView: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let row     = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TeilnehmerTVCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TeilnehmerTVCell
        //TODO: don't just pass the user.. fill the rows elements from here
        row.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        row.user    = users[indexPath.row]
        row.confBounds()
        return row
    }
}

//MARK: - TVDelegate
extension PeopleTableView: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return height
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        guard let id = users[indexPath.row].uid else { return }
        delegateTVToSingleEvent?.gotoProfile(clickedUID: id)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's a size issue on your table view. In order to test it, just set clipToBounds to true on your table view, this might illustrate your issues. Usually if your tap doesn't work you have 3 cases, userInteraction is disabled, the view is covered by another view, or the content is outside the bounds of the container.

Comment: I tried it, but sadly nothing changes. I'll give the views a border and see if they are overlapping or something.

Comment: You were right, the contentView just ends in the middle of the screen.. The contentView is inside a UIScrollView and does not scroll with it, even though the content is displayed correctly.